# LIB file generation in DLL project

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2005

I am using VC++ / Visual Studio 2005. I created a DLL project. The output DLL is getting created properly. But the associated LIB file is not getting created. Where might I go wrong? Do I have to do any special setting for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check if this worked

http://binglongx.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!142CBF6D49079DE8!274.entry

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to export something.